# "Cannot find folder" error uploading QGis plug-in to official repository

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I am trying to upload a QGis plug-in to the [official repository](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/add/). When uploading the `.zip` file I always get back this error message:

> There were errors reading plugin package (please check also your
>   plugin's metadata). Cannot find a folder inside the compressed
>   package: this does not seems a valid plugin

The contents of the `.zip` file are as follows:

```
.
├── dialogue_load.py
├── dialogue_load.ui
├── dialogue_new.py
├── dialogue_new.ui
├── help
│   ├── build
│   ├── make.bat
│   ├── Makefile
│   └── source
│       ├── conf.py
│       ├── index.rst
│       ├── _static
│       └── _templates
├── hex_utils_qgis.py
├── i18n
│   └── af.ts
├── icons
│   ├── Load.png
│   └── New.png
├── __init__.py
├── LICENCE
├── Makefile
├── metadata.txt
├── pb_tool.cfg
├── plugin_upload.py
├── pylintrc
├── README.md
├── resources.py
├── resources.qrc
├── scripts
│   ├── compile-strings.sh
│   ├── run-env-linux.sh
│   └── update-strings.sh
└── test
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── qgis_interface.py
    ├── tenbytenraster.asc
    ├── tenbytenraster.asc.aux.xml
    ├── tenbytenraster.keywords
    ├── tenbytenraster.lic
    ├── tenbytenraster.prj
    ├── tenbytenraster.qml
    ├── test_hex-utils-qgis_dialog.py
    ├── test_init.py
    ├── test_qgis_environment.py
    ├── test_resources.py
    ├── test_translations.py
    └── utilities.py
```

What is missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at a few zip files already on the plugins site and open up their zip files, you'll see that the zip file contains a folder with the plugin name at the top level, and the contents of your project go underneath that

```
my_plugin
    <your project here>
```

I suspect this is so the user can very easily extract to their **~/.qgis2/python/plugins** folder without needing to create a separate folder for the plugin.

If you're using the Plugin Builder plugin (I'm guessing from the presence of the Makefile) then running **make zip** will do the neccessary bundling up for you

(Been a while since I wrote a plugin, but hopefully it's still the same procedure as before)

Comment: `make zip` fails, for some reason it tries to copy the plug-in folder into itself. Therefore I zipped the hole thing including the root folder, and in that form the upload succeeded.